# Spotify api recently played paging

Tags: spotify

When I'm fetching my listening history with this URL : https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=50

I'm getting a "next" attribute from the response to fetch the previous data.

When I'm fetching API with this "next" url (i.e https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?before=1557334757252&limit=50), it returns an empty tracks array.

I don't understand why I'm getting an empty array.

PS : I obviously listened to more than 50 songs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Returns the most recent 50 tracks played by a user. Note that a track
>   currently playing will not be visible in play history until it has
>   completed. A track must be played for more than 30 seconds to be
>   included in play history.

Spotify stores 50 recent tracks information only. Since you already retrieved 50 records there is no use for using **after or before** cursor.Use limit which is not 50 then you can use the cursors.